# How to attach a non persisted information to an object in Django Rest Framework model serializer and ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My goal is to transfer a query property from the request to the response without persisting this property.

I am building an API endpoint using Django Rest Framwork ModelSerializer and ModelViewSet.

This endpoint let the user create multiple buildings at once. The response of this endpoint is a JSON array of created buildings. Each building contains a unique ID (called `rnb_id`) generated before saving the model to the db.

I want my user to know the unique ID of each the building they sent. To do so I want to let them attach a custom_id for tracking purpose. Important: I do not want to persist this custom id.

Here is and example of the request they send me:

```json
[
  {
    "geometry": [GeoJSON geometry],
    "custom_id": "XYZ"
  },
  {
    "geometry": [GeoJSON geometry],
    "custom_id": "FOO"
  },
  {
    "geometry": [GeoJSON geometry],
    "custom_id": "BAR"
  },
]
```

The response I would like to send them back is:

```json
[
  {
    "geometry": [GeoJSON geometry],
    "custom_id": "XYZ"
    "rnb_id": "randomID-zefjf"
  },
  {
    "geometry": [GeoJSON geometry],
    "custom_id": "FOO",
    "rnb_id": "randomID-oyijkn"
  },
  {
    "geometry": [GeoJSON geometry],
    "custom_id": "BAR",
    "rnb_id": "randomID-dwdsq"
  },
]
```

I feel the mechanism should be in the serializer. Here is a simplified version of my serializers:

```py
class BdgInAdsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    geometry = serializers.DictField(source="ads_geojson", required=False)
    rnb_id = serializers.CharField(validators=[ads_validate_rnbid])

    class Meta:
        model = Building
        fields = ["rnb_id", "geometry"]
        validators = [BdgInADSValidator()]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if validated_data.get("rnb_id") == BdgInADS.NEW_STR:
            # Geometry
            geojson = validated_data.pop("ads_geojson")

            geometry = GEOSGeometry(str(geojson))

            if geometry.geom_type == "Point":
                validated_data["point"] = f"{geometry}"

            if geometry.geom_type == "MultiPolygon":
                validated_data["shape"] = f"{geometry}"
                validated_data["point"] = f"{geometry.point_on_surface}"

            validated_data["rnb_id"] = generate_id()
            validated_data["source"] = "ADS"

            bdg = super().create(validated_data)

           # I tried to attach information on the model here but it does not "stick"

           return bdg

        else:
            return Building.objects.get(rnb_id=validated_data["rnb_id"])


class ADSSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    buildings_operations = BuildingsADSSerializer(many=True, required=False)
```

I have tried many approaches. My best hope was a [django proxy model] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) but it dit not work. It seems than anything I attach during the `create()` function does not stick and is not transfered to the response part.

I must precise, I do not want to alter my Building model. The tracking of this custom_id should be a mechanism of the endpoint.

Comment: [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Comment: I did try it but still could not transfer from request to response version of the serialized object

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [APIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views)?